# probability with bayes theorem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, bayes-theorem

I have a question on probability

[image]

The question requires the method of Bayes Theorem and here's what I've tried;

[image]

I'm not sure if i did it correctly. Would be great if anyone could inform me that it's right or wrong.

Comment: Perfect!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Images are generally discouraged. Please type out your work. You can find a detailed formatting tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).